# Sending repetitive email without an alias sender

Tags: python, email, smtp, mailchimp, sendgrid

I need to send about 1,000 emails. The emails are semi-personalized, though generic enough that they can inherit a default template.

This is easy enough to do in SendGrid, by iterating over a `for` loop and sending an email to each recipient.

However, when sending something in SendGrid, it notifies the recipient (if they look) that the email did NOT come from an individual's mailbox, but was mailed through a program. This looks bad if you are trying to personalize an email.

Currently, I am manually sending out the emails (copy and pasting from a template and then altering the necessary parts). Is there a way to automate this process **without** giving away the fact that the email is not being sent from a personal inbox (or a way to fake that)?

Copy and pasted from gmail:

```
from:        Delivery Notification <delivery@example.net> via sendgrid.me 
to:          recipient@example.net
date:        Thu, Mar 14, 2013 at 9:55 AM
subject:     Some Subject
mailed-by:   sendgrid.info
signed-by:   sendgrid.me
```

Comment: Could you provide more details about what you're seeing when you say that SendGrid notifies the recipient that it came from a program?  Sounds like your whitelabel settings might be off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your whitelabel settings are misconfigured.  You can use the whitelabel wizard under your SendGrid dashboard or follow along in the docs:

> http://sendgrid.com/docs/User_Guide/whitelabel_wizard.html

Contact our support team if you need help!

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Mandrill API](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/). It's made by MailChimp, but works more like SendGrid.